# How to use boolean function inside class in Arduino?

Tags: function, class, arduino, boolean

I am making a library for the MPR121 sensor and in that I want to use a bool function inside a class in Arduino IDE but it is not working.
Here's my code.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_MPR121.h"
#ifndef _BV
#define _BV(bit) (1 << (bit)) 
#endif
Adafruit_MPR121 cap = Adafruit_MPR121();
uint16_t lasttouched = 0;
uint16_t currtouched = 0;

class PaperTron {
  private:          
         uint8_t i;
         uint8_t a;
  public:
  PaperTron(){
}

void touchBegin(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hi! I'm PaperTron.");
  if (!cap.begin(0x5A)) {
  Serial.println("Error! TOUCH pins not found. Please check wiring.");
  while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Hurray! Now you can use my TOUCH pins.");
}  

**//This is the boolean function which is not working**
bool isHigh(uint8_t touchpin) {
  currtouched = cap.touched();
  for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
    if ((currtouched & _BV(i)) && !(lasttouched & _BV(i)) ) {
      if(i==touchpin) return true;  
    }
      if (!(currtouched & _BV(i)) && (lasttouched & _BV(i)) ) {
      if(i==touchpin) return false;
      }
  }
  lasttouched = currtouched;
 }
};

PaperTron papertron;
void setup() {
    papertron.Begin();
    papertron.touchBegin();
}

void loop() {
if(papertron.isHigh(2)){Serial.println("Hello");}
}
```

The serial monitor is showing "Hello" continuously whereas it should print "Hello" only when I press the touch pin on MPR121.

Comment: What is `isHigh` supposed to return if the loop checks all bits and finds no changes? How would you distinguish that from a bit that *did* change? I would have expected compile errors for a function that didn't return a value - unless I'm reading it all wrong.

Comment: @aMike The function is returning High that's why the if condition is getting executed.